# Set auto focus on next button

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I have wizard in extjs, where I place next, back and cancel button.
As per requirement I need to set focus on next button automatically. How to do it.

```
buildButtons : function() {
    return [
    {
        text:'Back',
        id:'backBtn',
        hidden:true,
        autoHeight:true,
        action: 'Back'
    },
    {
        text:'Next',
        id:'nextBtn',
        autoHeight:true,
        hidden:false,
        action: 'Next'
    },
    {
        text:'Finish',
        id:'finishBtn',
        autoHeight:true,
        hidden:false,  // Comments below line if you want finished button on each panel.
        //hidden:true,
        action: 'Finish'
    },
    {
        text:'Cancel',
        id:'cancelBtn',
        autoHeight:true,
        hidden:false,
        action: 'Cancel'
    }
    ];

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the latest version (4.1.1)

Get the button reference and call [focus](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.button.Button)

You should do this with the afterrender event of either the button itself or the component that hold the button.

***Example that can be executed directly in one of the API code-boxes***

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    defaults: {
        xtype: 'button'   
    },
    items   : [
        {
            text: 'Next',
            action: 'next'
        },
        {
            text: 'Prev',
            action: 'prev'
        },
        {
            text: 'Cancel',
            action: 'cancel'
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(b) {
            b.down('button[action=next]').focus(false, 100);  
        }
    }
});
```

Edit to answer to the comment:

Based on the given information I suggest you are using the [buttons](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.panel.Panel-cfg-buttons) config property to place your buttons. In your case I would recommend you to use the dockedItems array instead of the convenience buttons array. Try the following:

```
dockedItems: [{
    xtype: 'toolbar',
    dock: 'bottom',
    ui: 'footer',
    defaults: {minWidth: minButtonWidth},
    items: [
        {
            text:'Back',
            id:'backBtn',
            hidden:true,
            autoHeight:true,
            action: 'Back'
        },
        {
            text:'Next',
            id:'nextBtn',
            autoHeight:true,
            hidden:false,
            action: 'Next'
        },
        {
            text:'Finish',
            id:'finishBtn',
            autoHeight:true,
            hidden:false,  // Comments below line if you want finished button on each panel.
            //hidden:true,
            action: 'Finish'
        },
        {
            text:'Cancel',
            id:'cancelBtn',
            autoHeight:true,
            hidden:false,
            action: 'Cancel'
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(b) {
            b.down('button[action=Next]').focus(false, 100);  
        }
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as @sra says, use something like:

```
Ext.getCmp('IdOfNextButton').focus();
```

Or better still from your form use one of the up/down methods to find it via a specific class rather than relying on an Id.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach, if you can use it, would be to use the defaultFocus config of Ext.window.Window.  From the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.0.7/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-cfg-defaultFocus):

> defaultFocus : String/Number/Ext.Component
>
> Specifies a Component to receive focus when this Window is focused.
>
> This may be one of:
>
> - The index of a footer Button.
> - The id or Ext.AbstractComponent.itemId of a descendant Component.
> - A Component.
>
> Available since: 4.0.0